# Best practice of integration testing with xUnit.net and another process dummy server

Tags: c#, unit-testing, integration-testing, xunit.net

Using xUnit.net, I want to unit test the client application to be tested with the dummy server.

The dummy server uses node.js, python, etc. and be executed as a separate process.

At this time, what is the best way to start and stop the dummy server synchronously with the testing?

For example, I would like to do the following

1. Start testing xunit.net with dotnet cli
2. Start a dummy server with the command: `pipenv run python -m http.server`
3. Repeat the test for the number of unit tests
4. When all the tests are completed, stop the dummy server

I understand that it is a best practice to run the server with Collection Fixtures if I can create a dummy server with .NET.

If it is a simple function like http.server, it will be readily made in .NET.
More complicated, but with python and/or node.js there may be times when I can quickly create dummy servers with rich libraries.

Comment: AFAIC there aren't any. If it's a cli you're after, write a script. If it's a CI, write a build step. end of the day this is waaay too specific for a generic `best-practice` to even exist. On a more personal note, writing tests that do actual calls to some node app is a waste of time. Use interface wrappers, Pose (https://github.com/tonerdo/pose/) or Microsoft Fakes to ensure YOUR code is always sending correct payloads. If the other side breaks, too bad so sad, wasn't your code...